# Does Moment Timezone automatically adjust the time based on DST when formatting a time string?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

I want to convert the UTC [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string into the user's local date time based on the user's Time Zone. I'm using moment-timezone to accomplish this task, and here is the code snippet:

```
const userTimezone = moment.tz.guess();
const time = moment.utc("2023-03-08T16:35:21.453")
                   .tz(userTimezone)
                   .format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A")
```

**Does Moment Timezone consider the DST rules of the selected time zone and apply the appropriate DST offset to the formatted time?**

If my date string falls under DST then will it automatically adjust for DST offset while formatting or do we have to adjust for DST Offset manually?

Comment: If you try say "2023-01-01T00" and "2023-07-01T00" with a location that observes DST you'll likely find out in less time that it took you to ask the question. ;-) The answer is "yes".

Comment: @Yogi—it's not deprecated, it's described as "done", i.e. no new features, serious bug fixes only. I think the OP's real issue is parsing the timestamp as UTC (which could be done by appending a Z and using *Date.parse*).